# Scripts not functioning properly after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a small piece of inline script which isn't functioning as expected after an ajax call.

Basically, the script works perfectly if a user arrives on the page directly, but will falter if a user navigates to the page it is implemented on from another page (via ajax).  Reloading the page fixes the issue so I'm putting it down to my script not accounting for the ajax call events.

What's should I be adding in here to make it ajax-compatible?

Here's the script in question:

```
// Referencing the colored shapes overlaid on the image
const overlayA = document.getElementById("table-top-A");
const overlayB = document.getElementById("table-top-B");
const overlayNet = document.getElementById("net-frame");

// User selects primary color

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color-block");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeTop;
}

function changeTop(e) {
  // get the hex color
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  // set the hex color
  overlayA.style.fill = hex;
  overlayB.style.fill = hex;
}

// User selects secondary color 

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("frame-block");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeFrame;
}

function changeFrame(e) {
  // get the hex color
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  // set the hex color
  overlayNet.style.fill = hex;
}


const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const container = document.querySelector(".slides");

const prevButton = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");

let current = 0;
let startX = 0;
let endX = 0;


let position = 0;

function slideWidth() {
  let totalWidth = 0;
  
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.width = slider.offsetWidth + "px";
    totalWidth = totalWidth +  slider.offsetWidth;
  });
  
  container.style.width = totalWidth + 'px';
}

function animate() {
  container.style.transform = `translateX(-${slider.offsetWidth * current}px)`;
  position = slider.offsetWidth * current;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function slideFoward() {
  if (current < slides.length - 1) {
    current++;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
}

function slideBack() {
  if (current > 0) {
    current = current - 1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
}

// LOAD EVENT
window.addEventListener("load", slideWidth);

// RESIZE EVENT
window.addEventListener("resize", slideWidth);

// BUTTON EVENTS
nextButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  
  slideFoward();
});

prevButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  
  slideBack();
});

// TOUCH EVENTS
container.addEventListener("pointerdown", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  
  startX = event.pageX;
});


container.addEventListener("pointerup", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  endX = event.pageX;
  if (startX - endX > 40) {
    slideFoward();
  }
  if (startX - endX < -40) {
    slideBack();
  }
});
```

I also notice that a jquery script used elsewhere on the site isn't affected by AJAX calls in the same way - If I used jquery to rewrite the problematic script would that solve the issue?

Here's the jquery slider that is working fine across the ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.demo').slick({ 

  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  swipe: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1900,
  swipeToSlide: true,
});

  $('.demo').on('click', '.slick-slide', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var index = $(this).data("slick-index");
    if ($('.demo').slick('slickCurrentSlide') !== index) {
      $('.demo').slick('slickGoTo', index);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: For dynamically generated content you need to use delegated event handlers. I'm not sure why this has been tagged with `jQuery`, as you're not using it...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan whoops, sorry - my original question made mention of another jquery script that was working fine elsewhere on the site but I didn't include the actual script. Have edited the Q to include it

Comment: `$('.demo').on('click', '.slick-slide', function` is jquery event delegation.  You need to use the same format/concept for newly created elements.  Or add events to the new elements *after* you create them (without duplicating events on existing elements)